# irreducibility of $x^2-a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> > Let $a$ be transcendental over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and let $F=\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$.
> >
> > Prove $p(x)=x^2-a$ is irreducible over $F$

I've been trying to understand this for a while now, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to prove this. I understand that there is no polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ with $a$ as a root, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  We're starting out, so there isn't much available to us: we know that, given two roots $b$ and $c$ of an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$, $K(b) \cong K(c)$ and the multiplicity of each root of an irreducible polynomial splitting over some extension field is the same.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: A polynomial without zeros in a given field has no linear factors over that field. If a polynomial of degree $\le 2k+1$ is reducible over a field, then one of its factors must be of degree $\le k$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My issue is that we're working in $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and I'm not sure how to think of the former.

Comment: Elements of $\Bbb{Z}_2(a)$ are of the form $m(a)/n(a)$ for some polynomials $m(x),n(x)\in\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$, try and use that. Sorry, I partly misread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\;x^2-a\;$ reducible in $\;F\;\implies \sqrt a\in F\;\implies\;\exists\,p(x)\,,\,q(x)\in\Bbb Z_2[x]\;\;s.t.\;\;$

$$\sqrt a=\frac{p(a)}{q(a)} $$

Square now and get a contradiction to the fact that $\;a\;$ is transcendental over $\;\Bbb Z_2\;$

Comment: Thanks, I see why this is the case.  I'll have a go at it now.

Comment: Indeed, @Lost...and there's still a little thing to prove there, uh?

Comment: Yes, and I think I've got it: assuming this is the case, we get a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ with $a$ as a root, which is a clear contradiction.
My issue was that I wasn't sure how to think about $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$, but I think I see it now.